# How to compare paragraphs?

Tags: javascript, html

im new to programming and i wish you could help me with my problem.

so i want to whenever i click on the button function fm() will work, and function fm() should compare paragraphs (e.g. if paragraph vara equals varb something will be written in paragraph match ,else write nothing).

my problem is how to compare these paragraphs below? would be great if you could help me with as easy codes as possible.

html

```
<p id="vara" ><span id="countera">0</span></p>
<p id="varb" ><span id="counterb">0</span></p>
<p id="match"></p>
<button onclick="fm()">Match</button>
```

javascript

```
function fm(){ // what should be coded here? }

var toAdda = 1;
setInterval(function fa1() {
var counta = parseFloat(document.getElementById("countera").innerHTML);
document.getElementById("countera").innerHTML = (!isNaN(counta) == true ? counta + toAdda : toAdda) ;
}, 3000);

var toAddb = 1;
setInterval(function fb1() {
    var countb = parseFloat(document.getElementById("counterb").innerHTML);
    document.getElementById("counterb").innerHTML = (!isNaN(countb) == true ? countb + toAddb : toAddb) ;
}, 3000);
```

Comment: If I understand the question right, this could be solved with RegEx. If that's not correct you could just use a simple `==` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simply achieved using an `if` statement, and an `==` operator. You can use the `innerText` DOM value of the paragraphs to get their inner Text, and compare them using the `if` statement. Here's some code:

```js
function fm() {
  if (document.getElementById("vara").innerText == document.getElementById("varb").innerText) {
    //Write to match
    document.getElementById("match").innerText = "something";
  } else {
    //Do nothing
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="vara"><span id="countera">0</span>
</p>
<p id="varb"><span id="counterb">0</span>
</p>
<p id="match"></p>
<button onclick="fm()">Match</button>
```

Now, if you change the "0" within either of the paragraphs, it will not print "something".

Comment: Anytime, happy new year!